# Forcing implementation of an interface without modifying class source file?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Is it possible to force the implementation of an interface in C++ without modifying the source file of the class that's gonna be implementing it? For example, suppose I include the source files for my class, but I don't wanna touch its source code, I just want this class to implement an interface I created in the code that included it.

Generalizing even more, is it possible to do it with a binary library, where I don't even know the source code?

The reason I'm doing this is that I want to import classes to my projects but want them to be untouched so people can use them in other codes just by copying the files from my project. I know it should be better to disponibilize the raw unmodified source code of the class in another place and modify it for my project but let's suppose I want to make my project extremely understandable for people who already know the class but don't know my specific interface I added to it.

Comment: [Concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) don't require changes to implementing classes.

Comment: You want to retroactively make a class appear to inherit from an interface without modifying the class's source code?   Why no, I don't think you can do that.